# Azure DevOps - pipeline variables - special char issue $$

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automation, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using DevOps pipeline to build and deploy to different environments

For one environment I am encountering this issue where i am using a Pipeline Variable with $$ in the value

For Example:
Password pipeline variable with value = `$omeCla$$Password`

When i deploy it fails and when i check the logs the password is displayed as $omeCla$Password. So basically when $$ are together it drops one $

For all variable i am using regex `__VaraibleValue__` and its working fine

I have tried:

`$omeCla$\$Password` to try and escape and it displays as `$omeCla$\$Password` . So basically \ doesn't work.
I tried `'$omeCla$$Password'` to try and escape and it displays as `'$omeCla$Password'`

I want to keep this value as a normal pipeline variable before review

So basically how can I escape this?

Or should I add a Secret Token here in the replace token task (see screenshot below)? and then make the pipeline variable secret? If so, what should I set for Secret Token? Also, in app.config in my repo what should I use instead of the regex `__VariableName__` that I use for normal variables?

[image]

Comment: What **step** fails? What are you doing in that step with that variable?

Comment: I added more details

Comment: Using single quotation in the value might be a solution. like '$omeClas$$_$$'

Comment: @IanOF how do you read the variable? with PowerShell?

Comment: Yes Powershell. we have normal pipeline variables that we use '\__variable__ ' regex in config  and this works fine expect for Passwords. When i make the password secret and use #{password}# in config it gives me  #{password}#. Maybe this regex is wrong

Comment: What task did your screenshot comes from?

Comment: Replace Token task @JaneMa-MSFT

Comment: Could you please provide the link for this task in the market place? I have tried [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=citrus-andriessen.cag-replace-tokens) task and [Replace Variables](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=baskarlingamdevops.build-task) task and both of them worked well. By the way, my test process was to replace the variable with the task and then print it by PowerShell task, and the result was `$omeCla$$Password `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to use 4 $. So if you have $$ together you need to add $$$$

Example: $someCla$$$$Password

@JaneMa-MSFT as requested

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1296808/azure-pipeline-how-to-escape-special-characters-in.html